# Django Admin - 404 Error when logging in

Tags: django, hosting, admin

When going to login to the Django admin on my page, I geta 404 error and a "/admin/login/ url is not defined".

I only get this error while in the Production of my project - it works just fine locally. I am using A2 hosting and their support team has not been able to help me solve this problem.

The stack trace as well as the error url are seen in the second image.

Let me know if you need to see any code, I am more than happy to share I just dont want to be here all day posing all of my .py files when most of them wont matter anyways.

[image: Error]

Code by request:

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^students/', include("students.urls")),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="home.html"), name="home"),
    url(r'^home/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="home.html"), name="home"),
    url(r'^about/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html"), name="about"),
    url(r'^how_to_sponsor/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="how_to_sponsor.html"), name="how_to_sponsor"),
    url(r'^malawi/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="malawi.html"), name="malawi"),
    url(r'^stories/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="stories.html"), name="stories"),
    url(r'^donations/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="donations.html"), name="donations"),
    url(r'^staff/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="staff.html"), name="staff"),
    url(r'^malawi_education/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="malawi_education.html"), name="malawi_education"),
]

admin.site.site_header = 'Maphunziro Project'
```

UPDATE:
I ran a migration and now the login screen displays like it normally does - I am still getting the login issue however.

Could this be a dependency problem? I have all of the same dependencies installed on the server as my localhost version but maybe I'm missing one that is required for production.

Comment: can you show me your root url.py ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the address without the trailing slash 'www.educate-malawi.com/admin/login'. You can take a look at the documentation regarding the APPEND_SLASH [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash).

Comment: That redirects me back to "'www.educate-malawi.com/admin/login/"
Also the url that has the error is generated by Django after entering my login-information